# Can I pass a generic class in a method?

Tags: c#, .net

I have many class called `ErrorHandler`, which does different things each.
Every class is inside a namespace.

So:

```
namespace1.ErrorHandler
namespace2.ErrorHandler
namespace3.ErrorHandler
```

refers to three different classes. I want to have a method with a generic `ErrorHandler` parameter; so due to the one I pass to that method, it use it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can do it with interface, say:

```
public class namespace1.ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler {
}    

public class namespace2.ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler {
}
....
```

and method that handles errors may look like this:

```
public void HandleError(IErrorHandler handler) {
}
```

so can use this like:

```
var erh1 = new namespace1.ErrorHandler();
var erh2 = new namespace2.ErrorHandler();

....
HandleError(erh1);
HandleError(erh2);
```

Comment: But what should I put inside `IErrorHandler`?

Comment: @markzzz You need to define `IErrorHandler`. It should contain definitions for whatever operations you wish to perform on the handler, eg `Write()` or whatever.

Comment: Let says I have the same method inside namespaceX.ErrorHandler `CatchError()`: how can I call it from `handler`? `handler.CatchError()` doesn't work

Comment: @markzzz: move that method to the interface, so all type of handlers will override is, so having interface type instance inside generic method handler you can call it.

Comment: It says somethings like ` Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'ISocialErrorHandler' is less accessible than method 'SocialEngine.HandleCustomErrors(ISocialErrorHandler, System.Net.WebException, bool)`

Comment: check that common methods between types have the same accesibility. usually it's a *public*.

Answer (score 1):

With polymorphism, yes you can, as long as they derive from a common `ErrorHandler` type, either an interface or base class.

Answer (score 1):

Have them all implement a common type.. `class` or `interface`:

```
interface IErrorHandler { }

class ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler {}
```

Then use that in your common method.

Answer (score 0):

Allow the different classes to extend the same interface for example IErrorHandler
and the the method that handles it will look like:

```
public void HandleError<T>(T errorHandler)
        where T: IErrorHandler
    {

    }
```

Comment: That's an unnecessary use of generics. `public void HandleError(IErrorHandler handler)` does the same job, more simply.